# GUI for running parameterized Postgres query

Tags: postgresql, parameter

I often have to debug really complicated SQL queries that have placeholders / parameters like `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` throughout them.

When I try to run such a query in pgadmin, I get:

> ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
>
> LINE 30: WHERE r.predecessor_account_id = $1

If I try to run the query in PSequel, I get:

> The # of binded parameters < the # of parameter markers

In code, I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg to handle the parameters.

What GUIs exist to allow me to paste a long parameterized Postgres query and then type in some parameters (in fields, not by editing anything in the query) and run the query?

Comment: That sounds like a perfect use case for the [generic_plan](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/generic-plan) extension.

Comment: @user_0 Thank you! If you write this as an answer, I'd accept it. It seems that I can paste my query as-is into Dbeaver and then press the Play button that has a green plus next to it (a right-pointing triangle and green `+`), and then it prompts me to provide values for each numbered variable. Great!

Comment: Ok :) Done as answer! I abandoned PGAdmin since they jumped on Phyton with version 4..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Dbeaver can fit your case. Also is pretty customizable:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566119/dbeaver-how-to-declare-variables-and-use-them